# Writing valid Excel file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, character-encoding, file-writing

I got an Endpoint that receives emails with `.xlsx` files as attachments. I want to save these file in my app, so I can later access the data.

After receiving the mail and its attachment - which has a mime_type of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`- I call

```
path = "data/emails/#{attachment.filename}"
File.write(path, attachment.body.decoded)
```

but I get this error:

> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x85" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

When I use add `.force_encoding('utf-8')` to the decoded body, it does succeed, but the file it writes becomes invalid. I cannot open it normally, nor access its data.

How do I write a normal Excel file?

Comment: Do you actually need to convert the format, rather than just copying it to your local filesystem?

Comment: It'd be great if I didn't need to convert it. I simply want to save it - which sadly fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
File.open( path, "w+b", 0644 ) { |f| f.write attachment.body.decoded }
```

Taken from here:
https://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/saving-attachments-with-ruby-1-9-2-rails-3-and-the-mail-gem/